# Tomar un valor especifico de una tabla Sql mediante VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hola soy nuevo manejando Sql Server y Visual Basic, tengo una pregunta que me resulta complicada. Tengo una tabla llamada empleado en la que se registran empleados con distintos campos mediante un store procedure, uno de los campos es el permiso que puede tener un usuario ya sea ADMIN o EMPLEADO, este campo esta definido como permiso varchar(20) al cual mando el contenido de un combobox segun se elija cuando se registra a dicho empleado, quiero saber una forma de validar si un empleado es ADMIN o EMPLEADO mediante VB, esto es para un login en el cual el empleado ingresa su usuario y contraseña, el proposito de mi pregunta es para identificar si, al momento de ingresar, el empleado cuenta con la variable permiso = admin o permiso = empleado.
No se si me habre explicado de forma correcta :c muchas gracias

Comment: Tendrás que crear una consulta sql que devuelva el valor de esa columna. Una vez recogida esa información, sólo tienes que tratar esa información en vb.net. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Tienes problemas con la consulta sql? ¿o con el acceso a DB en vb.net?

Comment: Tengo una consulta que vendria siendo esta SELECT nom_usuario, contrasena from usuario WHERE nom_usuario = nombre AND contrasena = pass dentro de un procedure, el problema es que no se como tomar el valor de admin_us  desde el procedure que estableci, perdon si no me se explicar o si esta revuelto lo que digo